# Execute multiple commands sequentially with libssh2

Tags: ssh, libssh2

I'm looking for a way to execute multiple commands sequentially. What I do right now is creating a mew channel for each command and close It. If I use just one channel I get an error that a channel can not be reused. But I'm not sure If this is the right way because opening a channel for each command sounds costly.

What I'm looking to do is creating a ssh connection to an OpenWrt device which contains an executable called uci which can modify the configuration files on the device and use It like this:

```
uci set network.lan.ipaddr='192.168.1.2'
uci set network.lan.dns='192.168.1.1'
```

My code is similar to this:

```
let tcp = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:22").unwrap();
let mut sess = Session::new().unwrap();
sess.set_tcp_stream(tcp);
sess.handshake().unwrap();
sess.userauth_agent("username").unwrap();

let mut channel = sess.channel_session().unwrap();
channel.exec("ls").unwrap();
channel.wait_close();
println!("#1 exit: {}", channel.exit_status().unwrap());

let mut channel = sess.channel_session().unwrap();
channel.exec("ls").unwrap();
channel.wait_close();
println!("#2 exit: {}", channel.exit_status().unwrap());
```

If I don't close the channel and execute 2 commands sequentially I get the error code -39(wrong usage).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share the code you've started with?

Comment: I've added some code example which is similar to my code with [ssh2](https://docs.rs/ssh2/0.5.0/ssh2/).